# How to pass function argument into a list in Erlang?

Tags: list, erlang

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on Erlang lists and I'm having difficulty passing an argument to a list. The following is the code, I'm unsure how to run it, I get the error,

exception error: no function clause matching insert

I've tried

cases:insert(1,[0]).

on the command line and many others...

```
-module(cases).
-export([insert/2]).

insert(X,[]) ->
    [X];
insert(X,Set) ->
    case lists:member(X,Set) of
        true  -> Set;
        false -> [X|Set]
    end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've posted works fine.

You may want to recompile it with `c(cases)` then give it a shot.

But it works just fine for me, I've copied and pasted it into cases.erl and this is the result of the command line:

```
7> cases:insert(0,[1]).                                                                             
[0,1]
```

Comment: Its weird,if you try to use the word set instead of Set you get an error. Thats what it was. I was using the code I typed with lower case letters and the code I posted was copied verbatim from the tutorial with no changes.

Comment: The reason is that `set` and `Set` are two different type of objects. The `set` is atom, a literal constant with a name, while `Set` is a variable. It's part of the Erlang syntax, it's a variable iff it starts with an uppercase letter or _.